# Analogue "else" for FindAll

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm curious if there is a certain analogue of `else` for `FindAll`? That is, if the condition of `FindAll` is true, that the `ForEach` is triggered (as provided), and if the condition is false, then something else works (for example, `FictionalSomething()`). thank

```
List.FindAll(x => x.Num == 1).ForEach(x =>
{
    // Do something if x.Num equally 1

}).FictionalSomething(x =>
{
    // Do something if x.Num not equal 1
});
```

At the moment I am doing as follows:

```
bool Else = true;

List.FindAll(x => x.Num == 1).ForEach(x =>
{
    Else = false;

    // Do something if x.Num equally 1
});

if (Else) { Do something if x.Num not equal 1 }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute something on every element of the list in a condition is not met, drop the `FindAll` and just use `ForEach` with an `if` block:

```
List.ForEach(x => {
    if (x.Num == 1) {
    {
        // Do something if x.Num equally 1

    }
    else
    {
        // Do something if x.Num not equal 1
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank. However, before performing the actions, I need to view the entire list, that is, first perform the FindAll.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not that big of concern, then a little bit cleaner one would be.

```
var condition = (YourClass x) => x.Num == 1; 
var matched = List.FindAll(condition);
var notMatched = List.FindAll(x => !condition(x));
matched.ForEach(x => {
  //... 
});
notMatched.ForEach(x => {
  //... 
});
```

Comment: Thank. This solution scans the list several times, which reduces performance. I am concerned about how, by looking at the list once to make a decision, true or false.